# stripe connect with three different account php

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to stripe connect payment with three different account.but i can't get success so if any one have knowledge of that please share so i can implement it.

Example=customer1 want to give $100 the money to customer2 and customer3 (application owner) need it's application fee $10.

```
Stripe::setApiKey('customer3 api key');
        try {
        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                "amount" =>  100 * 100, // amount in cents, again
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => 'customer1 account token',
                "description" => 'xzx@xyx.com',
                "application_fee"=> 10*100,
                "destination" => 'customer2 account number')
              );
        $customer_array = $charge->__toArray(true);

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the platform account will be able to take an application fee. In that sense, customer1 should just be a user on the website making a payment (i.e a user checking out on your site or a customer whose payment details have been saved -- not a connected account), customer2 would be the connected account [0], and customer3 would be the platform account (the main Stripe account your application is using).

You won't be able to further split the payment further. For example, making a charge and sending the application fee to one connected account and the remainder of the payment to another connected account will not work:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-a-charge-s-funds-be-split-among-different-connected-accounts

Likewise, the `source` should be a token representing payment details as opposed to an account token or account ID. You won't be able to charge a connected account directly using the account ID. There's more info about how the payment process works with Connect that should be useful here:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts